# Wordpress Favicon Malware

Tags: wordpress, malware, malware-detection

**favicon.ico malware wordpress**

One of my client wordpress website affected with malware. the files are affected in root index.php, wp-settings.php and created some .3433232.ico files in wordpress.

Comment: The same thing as always, wipe everything and restore from backup?

Comment: This is not even a proper question.

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned a website last week who's having .ico virus included in all header.php themes files and also an SQL Injection who remake the malware once removed.

You must remove the SQL Injection in the first time then you need to install wordfence and do a full high sensitive scan to remove&repair files.

To find where the SQL Injection is stored, you have to do a search on PHPMyAdmin using these keywords : (functions used to run encoded php code)

eval(), base64_decode(), gzinflate(), str_rot13().

Try to analyse the code before removing it.

You can also use your FTP Client to connect on your server and filter by date to get last modified files.

Think about saving a copy of www&database before doing anything.

Here is a complete guide for removing wordpress malware that i've found and helped me a lot :

https://www.webarxsecurity.com/comprehensive-wordpress-malware-removal-guide/

Good luck